# How to eval an XSL constructed XPath expression

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

Humm...

```
<xsl:value-of select="$document/@*[name() eq $attrName]"/>
```

seems to be the solution...
Regards,
Christophe

I have a variable that contains the name of an attribute to query. How can I wrote such an XPath expression ?
Here is an example of what I would like to do

```
<xsl:variable name="attrName" select="$config//conf:document[@id=$docId]/@archive-ventil-attr"/>
<xsl:value-of select="$document/@{$attrName}"/>
```

I use XSLT 2.0

Thanks a lot in advance,
Christophe

Comment: The normal way to answer your own question is to add an "answer" containing your answer, then Accept it (click the checkmark). Alternatively, since you basically used @Martin's answer, you could just Accept that one.

Comment: @LarsH, I don't think this user would ever respond .. I have come across many such users, who create account ask a question, forget it after gaining answer .. they will never come back :) so there will be only 1 Q in activity history.

Answer (score 3):

With a complete XPath expression you would need an evaluate function which is in XSLT 1.0 and 2.0 only available as an extension, see [saxon:evaluate](https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/functions/saxon/evaluate.html). Also, in XSLT 3.0 (https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#element-evaluate) (since Saxon 9.8 and later PE and EE, Altova XML 2017 R3 and later) there is an instruction element named [xsl:evaluate](https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/xsl-elements/evaluate.html).

As long as you simply have a string with a local name it should suffice to use `<xsl:value-of select="$elements/@*[local-name() = $attrName]"/>`. This assumes `$elements` is a node-set (XPath 1.0) or sequence (XPath 2.0) of element nodes.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's what I've tried. Unfortunately, I'm limited to Saxon-HE, so xsl:evaluate is not a solution for me.